# Local work size for two dimensions

Tags: opencl

I am trying to code in a nested for loop for an opencl application which I am treating as a two dimensional problem. The global work size is not the multiple of the block_dimension and so I am declaring the sizes:

```
size_t global_work_size[2] = {length1,length2};
size_t local_work_size[2] = {NULL,NULL};
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, Kernel, 2, NULL, global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I am getting CL_INVALID_WORK_SIZE error. What should I change my local work size to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juste call the kernel like that:

```
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, Kernel, 2, NULL, global_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: I tried that before and it gave me an access violation reading location.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that this error wasn't coming from the fact that you were using NULL for the local size. the effect of using NULL is even explained in the [standard](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html): *local_work_size can also be a NULL value in which case the OpenCL implementation will determine how to be break the global work-items into appropriate work-group instances.*

Comment: It was a problem of accessing the buffers. Thank you.